# How to consume WCF .svc service in iOS 8 using swift?

Tags: ios, web-services, wcf, swift, xcode6

I am beginner in iOS & i want to call WCF .svc service from my application using swift.

My service return soap data in response.

I have consumed asmx service using following code ,can same code be used to call wcf .svc service or i do need to change the code.

```
 var celcius = txtCelsius.text

    var soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns='http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/'><Celsius>\(celcius)</Celsius></CelsiusToFahrenheit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"


    var urlString = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"



    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    var msgLength = String(countElements(soapMessage))

    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) // or false

    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()

    if (connection == true) {
        var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
    }
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

```
    var urlString = "http://assetwebservice.sudesi.in/service.svc"

    var msgLength = String(count(soapMessage))
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    var theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.addValue("http://tempuri.org/IService/BindCategory", forHTTPHeaderField: "Soapaction")
    theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)


    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self,startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()

    if (connection == true) {
        println("Connection success")
        var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
    }else{
        println("Error in connection")
    }
```

Hi Please check it always be in else condition means Error in connection 
Can't get result 
Thanks